# How can I load texture in scenes subclass?

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I have a loading scene which preloads my textures..

```
preload() {
  this.load.image("ship", "./assets/ship.png")...
```

and a level-scene with a custom player object..

```
export class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {

constructor(scene: Scene) {
    super(scene.matter.world, 64, 64, "ship", undefined, {
      friction: 0.025,
      frictionAir: 0.25,
   }); ...
```

but inside that player object i can´t set textures, it has no effect.

in level-scene:

```
create(){
  this.player = new Player(this);...
```

how can i load textures inside the player subclass of the level-scene? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add the sprite to the scene, with the command `scene.add.existing(this);` currently only the physics object is added.

**Here a small Demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {
    constructor(scene) {
        super(scene.matter.world, 64, 64, "blue", undefined, {
            friction: 0.025,
            frictionAir: 0.25,
        }); 

        scene.add.existing(this);
    }
}

class Example extends Phaser.Scene {
    preload () {
        this.load.image('blue', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/columns-blue.png');
    }

    create () {
        //const rect = this.matter.add.image(200, 50, 'blue');
        this.player = new Player(this);
     
    }
}

const config = {
    width: 500,
    height: 185,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: Example
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, it worked with just that one line: scene.add.existing(this);